# Origin of “quid” in its sense of a sovereign or guinea

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

What is the etymological origin of *quid* in its sense of a sovereign or guinea?
While preparing the question [Origin of “not for quids” phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96067) I noticed that  etymonline's *[quid](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=quid)* entry merely says

> "one pound sterling," 1680s, British slang, possibly from quid "that which is" (c.1600, see quiddity), as used in quid pro quo (q.v.)

Of this usage OED1 says, in part,

> [Of obscure origin] 1, A sovereign; a guinea.
>   (Pl. usually without *-s*, as *two quid, a few quid*, etc.).
>   1688 SHADWELL *Sqr. Alsatia* III. i, Let me equip thee
>   with a Quid.

In previous questions where *quid* is prominent ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27944/are-pounds-sterling-referred-to-as-squid-in-addition-to-quid)) or peripheral ([2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/953/informal-terms-for-money-amounts), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/origin-of-to-be-into-someone-for-a-sum-of-money)) I've seen nothing about the origin of the term.  In a comment to [my previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96067), MετάEd asserts that “Quid" (money) is widely believed to derive from "quid pro quo" anyway.”  But what evidence is available about the origin of *quid* in its sense of a sovereign or guinea?

Comment: My dictionary gives a flat "origin unknown."

Comment: Quid and quiddity have both been borrowed from Latin to mean "a thing" and "thingness" as far back as Old English. It's pretty obviously from that family of Latin words, albeit uncertain w/r/t the specific original idea.

Comment: Ily, your "obviously from" is like the "possibly from" and "perhaps from" phrases already present in the question and answers: it introduces a hypothesis or conclusion rather than evidence.  The question asks, "what evidence is available...?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED is less confident than some other sources:

> Origin uncertain; **perhaps** [from] classical Latin *quid* ‘what',
>   reinterpreted within English to refer to (monetary) means or
>   wherewithal. (My emphasis.)

Comment: What is that quoting?

Comment: @MετάEd. As I indicated, the OED.

Comment: Sorry, the first line didn't reproduce on my handheld. As a result I asked a stupid question.

Comment: @MετάEd. Understood.

Answer (score 7):

According to Milroy J. and Milroy. L, "Authority in Language" (1985),

> [...] *quid pro quo* probably gave rise to the slang "quid", a unit of money which varies with the context in which it is used.

And the plural is often the same as the singular. (same reference)

Comment: "a unit of money **which varies with the context** in which it is used." A quid varies? No wonder I have no idea how much stuff costs on British TV programs!

Answer (score 0):

My mother told me that another use for quid was as a term for a lump of phlegm coughed up. That it was green and, so she seemed to infer, squarish, connected it it to a pond note. Which came first, though, though, I don't know.

Comment: Considering that green pound notes were only introduced in the 1920s, this connection can only have been made then. And *quid* for *pound* has been around since the 1680s.